# AWS.config.credentials.identityId not found in typescript

Tags: aws-sdk-js

Following the guide I would like retrieve a unique Amazon Cognito identifier (identity ID) after I've set the login tokens in the credentials provider, but I'm not able to take the identityId in  AWS.config.credentials.identityId (but i can see it if I use console.log(AWS.config.credentials);.

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(AWS.config.credentials as AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials).identityId

It seems to work